# Simulação FM em Python

Tags: python, dsp

Estudo o terceiro semestre de engenharia elétrica, meu professor comentou que é possível simular modulações de sinais programaticamente, tive uma breve introdução a lógica de programação no curso, mas não consigo imaginar como por exemplo ondas de rádio FM poderiam ser simuladas dentro de um algoritmo, alguém tem experiencia com esse tipo de assunto ?

Answer (score 2):

Eu posso tentar ajudar sim, presumo que o seu professor tenha falado sobre simular modulação de demodulação.

> como por exemplo ondas de rádio FM poderiam ser simuladas dentro de um
>   algoritmo

Vamos deixar as coisas claras, as leis físicas que regem o universo permitem transportar frequências em forma de ondas eletromagnéticas, a maneira mais simples que eu consigo imaginar para explicar é que as ondas de rádio são apenas ondas eletromagnéticas que se propagam no vácuo na velocidade da luz, estas ondas são criadas quando uma antena perturba elétrons livres para oscilarem a uma frequência desejada (frequência da estacão de rádio por exemplo), desse modo a corrente produzida pela antena irá criar um campo magnético se propagando ao redor da antena, portanto a indução de um campo elétrico promove a variação do campo magnético formando o electromagnetismo, falei tudo isso para dizer que esse processo é físico e portanto não tem muito o que simular, mas a coisa muda de figura quando falamos do processo de modulação e demodulação, quando falamos de `FM=Frequency Modulation` estamos utilizando a natureza nosso favor para colocar informações dentro de uma determinada faixa de frequência que irá transportar nossos dados pelo ar, ou seja transportar informações através de uma onda portadora (um cosseno ou seno), podemos fazer isso dentro de um programa, podemos modular um sinal e despejar depois este sinal em uma antena e também é possível fazer o inverso pegar o sinal de uma antena e demodular dentro de um algoritmo, podemos também apenas modular um sinal dentro de uma frequência portadora e depois demodular para entender como o processo funciona.

Para transmissão e recepção de rádios `FM` comerciais foi definido que deve ser utilizado frequências entre `88 à 108 Mega Hertz`, existem algumas regras, a banda utilizada deve ser de 150K Hz (150 mil hertz), portanto a modulação vai ocorrer dentro desta faixa, um rádio transmitindo na frequência de `88Mhertz` modula suas frequências entre `(88-0.15)=87.85MHz à 88.15MHz=(88+0.15)`

Posso demonstrar estes passos utilizando matlab:

```
[m, fs, bits]=wavread('C:\Users\GTI\Desktop\Eder\Python26\tech.wav');

m=m(:,1);


portadora=88*10^6 %FM radio 88Mhz
fsm=((108*10^6)*2);
desvio=75000;


l = length(m);
t = 0:1./fsm:(l-1)./fsm;
int_m = cumsum(m)./fsm;
s = cos((2*pi.*portadora.*t)' + 2*pi.*desvio.*int_m);
```

A variável `s` contem seu sinal modulado dentro da frequência portadora, neste caso `88MHz`, agora podemos plotar esse sinal modulado e verificar como fica o sinal no domínio da frequencia:

```
lolu=fft(s);
Nyquist = fsm / 2;
MinFrequency=Nyquist / (length(lolu) / 2);
Frequency=((MinFrequency):MinFrequency:Nyquist);
plot(Frequency, abs(lolu(1:length(lolu)/2)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E todas as vezes que eu faço isso eu acho incrível lol, OK a simulação não esta perfeita dá para notar que o desvio transbordou a banda desejada 150Khz, mas está lá 88MHz com as modulações ao seu redor.

Mas e agora para pegar o sinal `s` e voltar para o sinal original (processo de demodulação), podemos simular novamente:

```
ini_phase = 0;
len = size(s,1);
if(len==1)
    s = s(:);
end


t = (0:1/fsm:((size(s,1)-1)/fsm))';
t = t(:,ones(1,size(s,2)));

yq = hilbert(s).*exp(-sqrt(-1)*2*pi*portadora*t-ini_phase);
z = (1/(2*pi*desvio))*[zeros(1,size(yq,2)); diff(unwrap(angle(yq)))*fsm];

% --- restore the output signal to the original orientation --- %
if(len == 1)
    z = z';
end

plot(z)
```

Se  tudo ocorreu bem você pode dar um `play` na variável `z` e escutar o seu sinal de volta...

Isso me fez imaginar que seria possível construir um aparelho que escutasse a faixa de espectro das rádio e que varresse todas as rádios disponíveis para a sua região em tempo real e sendo demostrados no espectro de frequências lol...